# Weird behaviour in Linux for a simple program

Tags: linux

We wrote a very simple C++ program to isolate a bug. The app takes a number as an argument and creates that number of threads and sends all those threads into an event loop. If we run app with >3 threads (including main thread) top shows it taking 100+MB in virtual memory. However, if we run it with <=3 threads, it runs with about 36MB virtual memory. We `strace`'d the app and found out that in the first scenario there is a `mmap` of about 65MB that is mapped anonymously that does not get unmapped. The problem is the memory usage goes up as the number of threads go up. And we have a large number of binaries which have large number of threads so there seems to be a lot of wasted space. Why does this happen? SLES11 64bit.

Comment: virtual memory != pysical memory -- having a huge number of threads will descrease performance a lot, you may consider using a thread pool or things like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each thread gets by default a stack of around 8Mb. You can set the default when you create a thread with [pthread_attr_setstacksize](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_getstacksize.html). Make sure you are *always* either: pthread_join()'ing threads that have ended. Or; create them as detached threads, otherwise you'll leak memory when a thread ends.

Having a big virtual memorry usage is usually not a problem though, unless you really are using all that space, it's just virtual memory - and you'll hardly run out of that on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: +1. @nos: So basically, nothing to worry about virtual memory usage on 64bit machines? Of course, the resident memory is very low for the process.

Comment: In principle, don't worry - there will be plenty of other things to worry about before that becomes a problem.